# Generate no of rows based on no.of checkboxes is checked

Tags: jquery

I have multiple checkboxes say 10.

each checkboxes contain unique value.

my requirement is,
i got to generate no.of rows in table based on now no.of check boxes is checked along with value of the check box should filled in the first td of the table row..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

**HTML**:

```
<input type='checkbox' value='1'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='2'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='3'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='4'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='5'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='6'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='7'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='8'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='9'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='10'/><br/>
<button>Generate table</button>
```

**JS**:

```
var table = $('<table>').appendTo('body');
$('button').click(function(){    
  $(":checked").map(function(){
    return $("<tr><td>" + $(this).val() + "</td><td></td></tr>");
  }).appendTo(table.empty());
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/c9DnE/)

The demo supposes you just have a table of 2 columns. The idea is simply get all the checked checkboxes via `:checked` selector, then use `.map` to turn this collection into a collection of the corresponding `tr` element. Then append this `tr` collection to the `table` after emptying the table.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy I understand what he need, although I know this is some kind of spoon and feeding, however I'm sure that in SO there are many many questions of the same kind, unless it's too broad, giving some answer is also OK. Also, it should be helpful for someone who will find this via searching.

Comment: if you gave me Down Vote .. then its also not good..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy no, I did not downvote you. BTW, I never care about other answers when I posted my own answer. Unless the problem is fairly hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for help or just wanting someone to do it for you?

You seem to already know all the steps -- read your checkboxes and create a new tr in the table for each checked on.

One possible example in horrible jquery:

```
jQuery('#add_to_table').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('.checkbox_class').each(function(i, checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) { 
            jQuery('#table_id').append( 
                jQuery('<tr/>').append(
                    jQuery('<td/>').text(checkbox.value)
                )
            )
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fg6K5/